# How do you use environment variables in Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Settings of Flash CS5?

Tags: environment-variables, path, flash

In Flash CS5, you can specify a Source path for the ActionScript settings so that the IDE can locate fully-qualified classes.  For example, to have Flash IDE locate "flashObjects.Balloon" class I might have the following set in my Source path list:

```
/Users/michaelprescott/Projects/XYZ/Experiments/Tester/src/flashObjects
```

This works fine, but is NOT portable.  I need a full path (not a relative one like ../../) that will work on other developer's machines including other OSX and Windows machines.  Surely there is a way to specify the most common environment variables.  I'm imagining something like:

```
$[USER_PROFILE_DIR]/Projects/XYZ/Experiments/Tester/src/flashObjects
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to the web, the following are what you have to work with:

- **`$(AppConfig)`**: Common/Configuration folder in the Flash install directory

  (`/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Common/Configuration`)
- **`$(LocAppConfig)`**: en_US/Configuration folder in the Flash install directory in English (respective folders for other languages)

  (`/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/en_US/Configuration`)
- **`$(UserConfig)`**: Configuration folder in the current user's Local Settings directory

  (`/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Flash CS5/en_US/Configuration`)
- **`$(LocalData)`**: same as UserConfig
- **`$(FlexSDK)`**: set by the user in preferences. May use other variables, and by default uses $(AppConfig)

Storing your objects in one of those spots would obviously work, but I bet that a symlink or two would make things even smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Why not place your files in the directory above your working directory. That way you only need to reference them like this:

```
../files
```

Putting that in place let's it be fully portable from ANY computer. Instead of specifying from the 'root' folder, you can start from the current folder. I have confirmed this to work.

**Important:** If you want to use this method and want to place a directory INSIDE your current working directory, you'll have to refer to it as such:

```
./files
```

Because just setting `files` as the source path won't work. As far as I know, this feature (environment variables) has long been asked for from Adobe and never acted upon. This seems to be the general work around for the time being.